# Java REST implementing custom authorization/authentication

Tags: java, security, rest

I'm working on a Java server exposing REST-ful interface. The calls to the interface are to be secured by username/password and each user is to have a role assigned, based on which the access to the resources are to be restricted. The server is hosted by Glassfish 3.1.
I need to implement a custom authorization/authentication scheme that is independent from the server (various reasons). So, after reading numerous articles on the topic, I never found one that quite explains how to implement that.
What I have so far is a custom Filter class that intercepts all the requests:

```
   public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException { }

    @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String user = "SalesUser";
    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
    roles.add("Sales");
    chain.doFilter(new UserRoleRequestWrapper(user, roles, request), response);
}
```

This filter class uses UserRoleRequestWrapper:

```
public class UserRoleRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    String user;
    List<String> roles = null;
    HttpServletRequest realRequest;

    public UserRoleRequestWrapper(String user, List<String> roles, HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        this.user = user;
        this.roles = roles;
        this.realRequest = request;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        if (roles == null) {
            return this.realRequest.isUserInRole(role);
        }
        return roles.contains(role);
    }

    @Override
    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        if (this.user == null) {
            return realRequest.getUserPrincipal();
        }

        // make an anonymous implementation to just return our user  
        return new Principal() {

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return user;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

So the filter intercepts the requests, I set a custom Principal (which will be based on the username/password provided). Also I can get that principal from SessionContext using getCallerPrincipal()
The problem is isCallerInRole() method. Even though I have assigned roles to my principle, it seems like isCallerInRole() looks somewhere else for the role. How can I set that role programatically in a way that is independent on the server that is hosting the application? 
Thanks :)